# Google_Auth_Exception: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-signin

I just run the example code from `https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts` for getting the access token.

But I am getting the following error from my code

```
Google_Auth_Exception: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }' in C:\xampp\htdocs\youtubeapi\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 363
```

My code

```
<?php

require_once 'Google/autoload.php';

$client_email = 'clinetemailis@7523.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('MyProject.p12');
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin');

$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
  echo "dfdsf";
}

$sqladmin = new Google_Service_SQLAdmin($client);
$response = $sqladmin->instances
    ->listInstances('examinable-example-123')->getItems();
echo json_encode($response) . "\n";
?>
```

please help. whats the actual issue here.

Code Update

```
<?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();
//'2015-08-28T00:00:00.000Z'
//'2015-08-29T00:00:00.000Z'
/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */


$client_id = 'dfgdfgdfg.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $Email_address = '456dsfd1@developer.gserviceaccount.com';   
    $key_file_location = 'Youtube API-asdasd.p12';      
    $htmlBody="";
    $client = new Google_Client();      
    $client->setApplicationName("Youtube API");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

    // seproate additional scopes with a comma   
    $scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($Email_address,         
                             array($scopes),        
                             $key);     

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
         $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);      
    }   
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['timeStart']) && isset($_POST['timeEnd']) && isset($_POST['Status']) && isset($_POST['dateStart']) && isset($_POST['dateEnd']))
{
  try {

    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's snippet. Specify values
    // for the snippet's title, scheduled start time, and scheduled end time.
    $startTime  = $_POST['dateStart']."T".$_POST['timeStart'].":00+0530";
    $endTime  = $_POST['dateEnd']."T".$_POST['timeEnd'].":00+0530";
    //$startDatetime = new DateTime($startTime);
    //$endDatetime = new DateTime($endTime);

    //$startDatetime = $startDatetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    //$endDatetime = $endDatetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    $broadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    $broadcastSnippet->setTitle($_POST['title']);
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($startTime);
    $broadcastSnippet->setScheduledEndTime($endTime);

    // Create an object for the liveBroadcast resource's status, and set the
    // broadcast's status to "private".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
    $status->setPrivacyStatus($_POST['Status']);

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveBroadcast resource.
    $broadcastInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();
    $broadcastInsert->setSnippet($broadcastSnippet);
    $broadcastInsert->setStatus($status);
    $broadcastInsert->setKind('youtube#liveBroadcast');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new broadcast.
    $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,status',
        $broadcastInsert, array());

    // Create an object for the liveStream resource's snippet. Specify a value
    // for the snippet's title.
    $streamSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStreamSnippet();
    $streamSnippet->setTitle('New Stream');

    // Create an object for content distribution network details for the live
    // stream and specify the stream's format and ingestion type.
    $cdn = new Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings();
    $cdn->setFormat("1080p");
    $cdn->setIngestionType('rtmp');

    // Create the API request that inserts the liveStream resource.
    $streamInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream();
    $streamInsert->setSnippet($streamSnippet);
    $streamInsert->setCdn($cdn);
    $streamInsert->setKind('youtube#liveStream');

    // Execute the request and return an object that contains information
    // about the new stream.
    $streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn',
        $streamInsert, array());

    // Bind the broadcast to the live stream.
    $bindBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->bind(
        $broadcastsResponse['id'],'id,contentDetails',
        array(
            'streamId' => $streamsResponse['id'],
        ));

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s published at %s (%s)</li>',
        $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $broadcastsResponse['snippet']['publishedAt'],
        $broadcastsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Added Stream</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $streamsResponse['snippet']['title'],
        $streamsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Bound Broadcast</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>Broadcast (%s) was bound to stream (%s).</li>',
        $bindBroadcastResponse['id'],
        $bindBroadcastResponse['contentDetails']['boundStreamId']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    //$htmlBody .="<h3>Live  Broadcast</h3><div>";

    //$htmlBody .= sprintf("<iframe id='ytplayer' type='text/html' width='640' height='390' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s?autoplay=1'  frameborder='0'></iframe>",
        //  $broadcastsResponse['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</div>';


  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
      // echo $e->getMessage();
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  } else {


}
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl" onclick="window.open('$authUrl', 'newwindow', 'width=600, height=400'); return false;">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bound Live Broadcast</title>
</head>
<body>

  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using this authentication for scheduling the live stream once i using this code. i am getting another error `Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet%2Cstatus: (403) Insufficient Permission`

How can i make my request with sufficient permission?

Comment: use `session_start();` after require the `'Google/autoload.php'`

Comment: I added session_start(); after the 'Google/autoload.php'.but still i am getting the same error

Comment: [Read this](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/) article

Comment: I just used some code from your article and the full code updated in my question. Can you please have look 'Code Update'

Comment: @Kichu have you solved the issue/? I am getting the same issue.. my same code was working fine 15 days ago.. but suddenly it stopped working..

Comment: Yes i solved the "invalid_grant" issue but still i am stuck with some authorization issues.

Answer (score -1):

**Your First code sample:**

Looks like you are trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL API, did you give the service account permissions to access it?

**Your Second Code sample:**

You are requesting the scope for Google Analytics

```
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";
```

But trying to make requests from YouTube

```
Google_Service_YouTube
```

Anwsers:

1. Scopes must match the service and permissions that you need.
2. The YouTube API doesn't support Service accounts you need to use Oauth2.

**Comment**

These code samples aren't alike you really should have had two questions one for the problem with Google cloud sql api the other for the YouTube api.